# One way to solve $\int_{0}^{\infty}3\Big(\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+1}+\frac{xe^{-x^3}}{x^3+1}-\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x^3+1}\Big)dx=G$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, constants

It's a simple question we have :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}3\Big(\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x+1}+\frac{xe^{-x^3}}{x^3+1}-\frac{e^{-x^3}}{x^3+1}\Big)dx=G$$

Where $G$ is the [Gompertz constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GompertzConstant.html)

It has a simple antiderivative wich is equal to :
$$eE_i(-x^3-1)$$

Where $E_i(x)$ is the [Exponential integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html)

Applying the Fundamental theorem of calculus we get the desired result .

My question :

Have you another way to prove it ?

Thanks in advance for all your contributions.